# Can a moderator delete "When will ArcGIS 10.0 SP1 be released?"

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation, deleted-questions

matt wilkiesaid I should delete my ArcGIS 10 SP questions, but I get this for SP1:  "Sorry, this question cannot be deleted: too many existing answers, or upvoted/accepted answers (click on this box to dismiss)"

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/when-will-arcgis-10-0-sp1-be-released

thanks.

i tried un-accepting answers, but I still can't delete.

i'll try closing it.

Answer (score 6):

Done.

The question could not be deleted because it already had answers. For future reference, the best way to handle any exceptional situation like this is to flag the post for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0):

I just went a step further, deeming the question and its answers to have no value to the site, and deleted the question, which deleted its answers too.

I suspect that @RobertCartaino used a smaller stick in [his answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/231/115) (nearly 6 years ago) because he was less familiar with GIS, and wanted to give the community a chance to develop its scope.